# Sybase - Return only data from last three days

Tags: sql, sybase, isql

I am fairly new to this. I have a statement where I want to only return the last three days of data based on shipment_datedelivered. What date functions can I use to achieve this? I am using Sybase.

```
 select dba.disp_ship.ds_id, dba.disp_ship.ds_origin_id, dba.disp_ship.ds_findest_id, dba.disp_ship.ds_billto_id, dba.disp_ship.ds_bill_charge, dba.disp_ship.ds_ref1_text,
dba.disp_ship.ds_status, dba.disp_ship.ds_bill_date, dba.disp_ship.ds_ship_date, dba.disp_ship.ds_ship_type, dba.disp_ship.movecode, 
dba.companies.co_id, dba.companies.co_name, dba.current_shipments.cs_id, dba.current_shipments.cs_event_count, dba.current_shipments.cs_routed, dba.current_shipments.cs_assigned, dba.current_shipments.cs_completed, dba.current_shipments.shipment_datedelivered,
(CASE ds_status WHEN 'A' THEN 'TEMPLATE'
WHEN 'C' THEN 'CANCELLED'
WHEN 'D' THEN 'DECLINED'
WHEN 'E' THEN 'QUOTED'
WHEN 'F' THEN 'OFFERED' 
WHEN 'H' THEN 'PENDING'
WHEN 'K' THEN 'OPEN'
WHEN 'N' THEN 'AUTHORIZED'
WHEN 'Q' THEN 'AUDIT REQUIRED'
WHEN 'T' THEN 'AUDITED'
WHEN 'W' THEN 'BILLED' 
END) AS 'BILLING STATUS',
(CASE ds_ship_type WHEN '2201' THEN 'MONTREAL'
WHEN '2202' THEN 'DRYVAN'
WHEN '2203' THEN 'BROKERAGE'
WHEN '2204' THEN 'OLD BROKERAGE (NO GOOD)'
WHEN '2205' THEN 'LIFTING'
WHEN '2206' THEN 'WAREHOUSE'
END) AS 'DIVISION',
(CASE WHEN dba.current_shipments.cs_event_count = dba.current_shipments.cs_completed
THEN 'OPEN COMPLETED' 
ELSE 'INCOMPLETE'
END) 
 AS 'STATUS' 
from dba.disp_ship
inner join dba.companies ON dba.disp_ship.ds_billto_id=dba.companies.co_id
inner join dba.current_shipments ON dba.disp_ship.ds_id=DBA.current_shipments.cs_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I just got it. I added this to the end of my query and I am now getting the desired data.

where shipment_datedelivered >= dateadd(day, -3, GETDATE())